# space-separated string of all positive numbers that are divisible by 2.For example, even_numbers(6) returns “2 4 6”

Tags: python

```
def even_numbers(maximum):
    return_string = ""
    for x in ___:
        return_string += str(x) + " "
    return return_string.strip()
print(even_numbers(1))  # No numbers displayed
```

Comment: could u format the code well? we can't understand much without indentation

Comment: What is your *question*?

Comment: this doesnt make much sense, this code.
u pass in 1 to even_numbers and u don't even use it, what do u want to do?

Comment: 0 is divisible by 2 so it should be included in your output. `___` should be `range(0, maximum+1, 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def even_numbers(maximum):
    return_string = ""
    for x in range(1,maximum+1):
        if x%2==0:
            return_string += str(x) + " "
    return return_string.strip()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
def even_numbers(maximum):
    return_string = ""
    for x in range(2, maximum + 1, 2):
        return_string += str(x) + " "
    return return_string.strip()


print(even_numbers(6))  # prints 2, 4, 6
```

Comment: bro it shouls print like should be 2 4 6 .if it is (1) No numbers displayed

Answer (score 1):

```
def even_numbers(maximum):
    return_string = ""
    for x in range(0, maximum + 1):
        if x != 0 and x % 2 == 0:
            return_string += str(x) + " "
    return return_string.strip()


print(even_numbers(6))  # Should be 2 4 6
print(even_numbers(10))  # Should be 2 4 6 8 10
print(even_numbers(1))  # No numbers displayed
print(even_numbers(3))  # Should be 2
print(even_numbers(0))  # No numbers displayed
```